# Applet Loading failed over SSL

Tags: java, applet, filenet-p8, filenet

I have an applet embedded in jsp (IBM FileNet JavaViwer) which loads the document in jsp page.

The applet loads fine over over http requests.

but with https i am facing problems.

Applet loads with https my devserver deployed on WAS (Without any webserver in place) jre5 or jre6 installed clients can view it perfectly.

But in my test environment where IHS server sit in front of WAS, Applet loading fails with classnot found exception for jre 5 clients.
for Jre 6 clients applet loads with https on test server as well.

Below is Java Console Log:

---

```
Java Plug-in 1.5.0_15
Using JRE version 1.5.0_15 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM
User home directory = C:\Users\user1


basic: Cache is enabled
basic: Location: C:\Users\user1\AppData\LocalLow\Sun\Java\Deployment\cache\javapi\v1.0
basic: Maximum size: unlimited
basic: Compression level: 0

basic: Plugin modality.register
----------------------------------------------------
c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
p:   reload proxy configuration
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to <n>
----------------------------------------------------

basic: Registered modality listener
liveconnect: Invoking JS method: document
liveconnect: Invoking JS method: URL
basic: Referencing classloader: sun.plugin.ClassLoaderInfo@ee6681, refcount=1
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.GrayBoxPainter@1fd6bea
basic: Loading applet ...
basic: Initializing applet ...
basic: Starting applet ...
basic: Referencing classloader: sun.plugin.ClassLoaderInfo@ee6681, refcount=2
basic: Releasing classloader: sun.plugin.ClassLoaderInfo@ee6681, refcount=1
basic: httpCompression = true
liveconnect: Invoking JS method: execScript
liveconnect: Invoking JS method: evalIntermediateValueToReturn
network: Connecting https://X.X.X.X:443/myApp/FnJavaV1Files/ji.jar with proxy=HTTP @ /Y.Y.Y.Y:8080
network: Connecting https://X.X.X.X:443/myApp/FnJavaV1Files/ji/applet/jiApplet.class with proxy=HTTP @ /Y.Y.Y.Y:8080
network: Connecting https://X.X.X.X:443/myApp/FnJavaV1Files/ji/applet/jiApplet/class.class with proxy=HTTP @ /Y.Y.Y.Y:8080
load: class ji.applet.jiApplet.class not found.
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ji.applet.jiApplet.class
 at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin.AppletViewer.createApplet(Unknown Source)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(Unknown Source)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
basic: Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ji.applet.jiApplet.class
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ji.applet.jiApplet.class
 at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
 at sun.applet.AppletClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.createApplet(Unknown Source)
 at sun.plugin.AppletViewer.createApplet(Unknown Source)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.runLoader(Unknown Source)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
basic: Plugin modality.pushed
basic: Modality pushed
basic: push javax.swing.JDialog[dialog0,549,317,268x134,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,modal,title=Error - Java,defaultCloseOperation=HIDE_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,3,25,262x106,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true]
basic: Plugin modality.pushed
basic: Modality pushed
basic: push javax.swing.JDialog[dialog0,549,317,422x303,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,modal,title=Error - Java,defaultCloseOperation=HIDE_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,3,25,416x275,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true]
basic: Plugin modality.popped
basic: Modality popped
basic: pop javax.swing.JDialog[dialog0,549,317,422x303,invalid,hidden,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,modal,title=Error - Java,defaultCloseOperation=HIDE_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,3,25,416x275,invalid,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true]
basic: Plugin modality.popped
basic: Modality popped
basic: pop javax.swing.JDialog[dialog0,549,317,422x303,invalid,hidden,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,modal,title=Error - Java,defaultCloseOperation=HIDE_ON_CLOSE,rootPane=javax.swing.JRootPane[,3,25,416x275,invalid,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=16777673,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=],rootPaneCheckingEnabled=true]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the Webserver in test environment is not supporting SSLV3 protocol. It supports only TLSV1. Jre 5 clients by default uses SSLv2Hello & SSLv3 so error is thrown as there is no common protocol. However jre 6 clients default runs on SSLv3 & TLV1, in this case TLSV1 is common protocol btw client and webserver and connection is succesful and applet loads fine.

Error message ClassNotFound is quite weird though..